# Sending the files (At least 11 files) from folder through web service to android app

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I stuck in middle of this situation,Please help me out.

My question is that I want to send files (Total 11 PDF Files) to android app using web service.

I tried it with below code.**Main Class from which web service is created**

```
public class MultipleFilesImpl implements MultipleFiles {

public FileData[] sendPDFs() {
    FileData fileData = null;
    // List<FileData> filesDetails = new ArrayList<FileData>();
    File fileFolder = new File(
            "C:/eclipse/workspace/AIPWebService/src/pdfs/");
    // File fileTwo = new File(
    // "C:/eclipse/workspace/AIPWebService/src/simple.pdf");

    File sendFiles[] = fileFolder.listFiles();
    // sendFiles[0] = fileOne;
    // sendFiles[1] = fileTwo;

    DataHandler handler = null;
    char[] readLine = null;
    byte[] data = null;
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    InputStream stream = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    FileData[] filesData = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Web Service Called Successfully");

        for (int i = 0; i < sendFiles.length; i++) {
            handler = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(sendFiles[i]));
            fileData = new FileData();
            data = new byte[(int) sendFiles[i].length()];
            stream = handler.getInputStream();
            while (offset < data.length
                    && (numRead = stream.read(data, offset, data.length
                            - offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }
            readLine = Base64Coder.encode(data);
            offset = 0;
            numRead = 0;
            System.out.println("'Reading File............................");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println(readLine);
            System.out.println("Data Reading Successful");

            fileData.setFileName(sendFiles[i].getName());
            fileData.setFileData(String.valueOf(readLine));

            readLine = null;
            System.out.println("Data from bean " + fileData.getFileData());

            outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:/"
                    + sendFiles[i].getName());

            outputStream.write(Base64Coder.decode(fileData.getFileData()));

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            stream.close();
            // FileData fileDetails = new FileData();
            // fileDetails = fileData;
            // filesDetails.add(fileData);
            filesData = new FileData[(int) sendFiles[i].length()];
        }
        // return fileData;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filesData;
}
```

}

Also The Interface MultipleFiles:-

```
public interface MultipleFiles extends Remote {
    public FileData[] sendPDFs() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
            Exception;
}
```

Here I am sending an **array of bean "File Data"**,having properties viz. FileData & FileName.
FileData- contains file data in encoded.
FileName- encoded file name.

The Bean:- (FileData)

```
public class FileData {
    private String fileName;
    private String fileData;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileData() {
        return fileData;
    }

    public void setFileData(String string) {
        this.fileData = string;
    }

}
```

The android DDMS gives out of memory exception when tried below code & when i tried to send two files then only first file is created.

```
public class PDFActivity extends Activity {
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "sendPDFs";
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://webservice.uks.com/";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
    private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.123:8080/AIPWebService/services/MultipleFilesImpl";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView textViewOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewOne);

        try {
            SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

            textViewOne.setText("Web Service Started");
            AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            // SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            Object result = envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("Result", result.toString());
            // String fileName = result.getProperty("fileName").toString();
            // String fileData = result.getProperty("fileData").toString();

            // Log.i("File Name", fileName);
            // Log.i("File Data", fileData);

            // File pdfFile = new File(fileName);


            // FileOutputStream outputStream =
            // openFileOutput(pdfFile.toString(),
            // MODE_PRIVATE);

            // outputStream.write(Base64Coder.decode(fileData));
            Log.i("File", "File Created");
            // textViewTwo.setText(result);
            // Object result = envelope.getResponse();
            // FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(name, mode)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help with some explanation or changes in my code.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Myself got the solution of this question.

The major problem I faced using kSoap2 api 2.4 version is that I can't able to get complex object (array of bean in my case)

Then I changed my code from this (using ver 2.4):-

```
try {
            SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

            textViewOne.setText("Web Service Started");
            AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            // SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            Object result = envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("Result", result.toString());
            // String fileName = result.getProperty("fileName").toString();
            // String fileData = result.getProperty("fileData").toString();

            // Log.i("File Name", fileName);
            // Log.i("File Data", fileData);

            // File pdfFile = new File(fileName);


            // FileOutputStream outputStream =
            // openFileOutput(pdfFile.toString(),
            // MODE_PRIVATE);

            // outputStream.write(Base64Coder.decode(fileData));
            Log.i("File", "File Created");
            // textViewTwo.setText(result);
            // Object result = envelope.getResponse();
            // FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(name, mode)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

to this code (using ver 2.5.1):-

```
    try {
        SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        for (int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            SoapObject object = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);

            Log.i("File Data", object.getProperty("fileData").toString());
            Log.i("File Name", object.getProperty("fileName").toString());

            pdfFiles = new File(object.getProperty("fileName").toString());
            outputStream = openFileOutput(pdfFiles.toString(), MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(Base64Coder.decode(object.getProperty(
                    "fileData").toString()));
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.d("File Creation Message", "Files Created Succesfully");
    } catch (SoapFault fault) {
        fault.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream = null;
        }
    }
```

Hence I got solution.

The main help is through the issue-24 of this :- Please read that if u are facing such problem.[Link-Issue-24](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=24)